# Insert a text file (object) as .txt into a cell of excel sheet using python

Tags: python

[image]

I want to embed a text file in to excel sheet using python (as shown above)such that when you click on that cell, the file automatically opens. I do not want to specify the path as hyperlink.like "c:\My Documents\xyz.txt". The reason for this is that I want the code to be portable , i.e., others should also be able to run the program on their computers in whichever folder they want to. In this situation the code wont work on other computers due to the path name specified.

```
import win32com.client as win32
xl = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = 1
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\\automation\\abcdef.xlsx")

column = wb.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A200")
Embedded_object = wb.ActiveSheet.OLEObjects()
i = 2
for cell in column:
    hostname_cell = wb.ActiveSheet.Cells(i,1).Value
    fi = 'C:\Users\\212632723\utomation\\geckodriver.txt'
    if hostname_cell is None:
        print fi
        xl.ActiveSheet.OLEObjects().Add(Filename=fi, Link=False, DisplayAsIcon=True).Select
        i += 1
```

I have used above code from [Embedding text file into excel using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27743237/embedding-text-file-into-excel-using-python)  to accomplish what i needed, but it throws an error

> xl.ActiveSheet.OLEObjects().Add(Filename=fi, Link=False,
>   DisplayAsIcon=True).Select   File "", line 6, in
>   Add com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft
>   Excel', u'Add method of OLEObjects class failed', u'xlmain11.chm', 0,
>   -2146827284), None)

EDIT :

```
import win32com.client as win32
xl = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = 1
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\\212632723\python_ui_automation\\abcdef.xlsx")

column = wb.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A200")
Embedded_object = wb.ActiveSheet.OLEObjects()
i = 2
for cell in column:
    hostname_cell = wb.ActiveSheet.Cells(i,1).Value
    fi = 'C:\Users\\212632723\python_ui_automation\\geckodriver.txt'
    if hostname_cell is None:
        print fi
        #xl.ActiveSheet.OLEObjects().Add(Filename=fi, Link=False, DisplayAsIcon=True).Select
        xl.ActiveSheet.OLEObjects().Add(Filename=fi, Link=False, DisplayAsIcon=True, IconFileName="excel.exe", IconIndex=0, IconLabel="IcoLabel").Select()
        i += 1
```

I have tried this based on the comments and it throws following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\212632723\python_ui_automation\hello.py", line 15, in
>   
>       xl.ActiveSheet.OLEObjects().Add(Filename=fi, Link=False, DisplayAsIcon=True, IconFileName="excel.exe", IconIndex=0,
>   IconLabel="IcoLabel").Select()   File "", line
>   6, in Add com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0,
>   u'Microsoft Excel', u'Add method of OLEObjects class failed',
>   u'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this post:

[Embedding text file into excel using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27743237/embedding-text-file-into-excel-using-python)

answers the first part of your question.

Concerning your path issue, you could try to use relative paths or environment variable (on Windows, you can rely on HOMEPATH).

Regards.

Comment: no, that does not work for me. throws following error
File "<COMObject OLEObjects>", line 6, in Add
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Excel', u'Add method of OLEObjects class failed', u'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

Comment: have you tried something like: xl.ActiveSheet.OLEObjects().Add(Filename=fi, Link=False, DisplayAsIcon=True, IconFileName="excel.exe", IconIndex=0, IconLabel="IcoLabel").Select

Comment: yeah have tried this but still i get error. have updated in question